# what is the best way to divide a list into two list based on a criteria

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of objects and I want to divide this list into two lists based on the value of a field. Here's how I did it with `Stream.filter()`:

```
public void setMovieMedia(List<MovieMediaResponse> movieMedias) {

    // fill the first list
    this.setPhotos(movieMedias
            .stream()
            .filter(movieMedia -> movieMedia.getType().equals(MediaType.PHOTO))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    // fill the second list
    this.setVideos(movieMedias
            .stream()
            .filter(movieMedia -> movieMedia.getType().equals(MediaType.VIDEO))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

However, with this approach, I think I am looping through the list twice. Is there a way to do achieve the same thing without iterating through the list twice?

PS: I know I can achieve this by using `List.forEach()` like in the following example, but I'd like to avoid using this method:

```
List<MovieMediaResponse> movieMedias = ...;
movieMedias.forEach(m -> {
    if (m.getType().equals(MediaType.PHOTO))
        // append to list1
    else if (m.getType().equals(MediaType.VIDEO))
       // append to list2
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Collectors.partitioningBy` that will get you a `Map` where key is a `Boolean`; thus you can do:

```
result.get(true/false)
```

to get each individual list. Since you seem to know your way around streams, I will not show an example, you can most probably figure it out